# Java object initialization with diamond operator terrible javac compile time performance

Tags: java, collections, type-inference, diamond-operator

I'm using the diamond operator to initiate objects within a list. However as the number of array objects increases, compile time increases from few seconds to hours. My eclipse auto build made my eclipse non-responsive. I then noticed it is a javac issue. When I replace all `<>` with `<String, List<Category>>` the compile time goes back to just a few seconds. Is this something I'm doing wrong or is it just a Java performance issue?

Here is my code which will take Java hours to compile (or crashes javac v8u25):

```
    List<Pair<String, List<Category>>> categoryMappings = null;

    public void reloadStaticData() {                  
      // Left one is the provider's category and right one is ours
      try(UoW luow = CoreModule.getInstance(UoW.class)) {
        CategoryRepo categoryRepo = luow.getCategoryRepo();
        categoryMappings = Arrays.asList(

                  // Nightlife
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Bars", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Ski-Bar", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Bar", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Beer", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Pubs", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Clubs", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())),
                  new ImmutablePair<>("Dance", Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get()
                          ,categoryRepo.findByName("Clubs").get())),    
                  // if I got more than 20 of these ImmutablePairs, javac crashes or takes hours to compile
      );
      }
    }
```

***Edit:*** 
As Sotirios mentioned in comments it seems to be a reported issue in JDK:

*type inference exponential compilation performance:*
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055984

*type inference performance regression:*
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048838

Comment: Are you sure its a javac problem? Eclipse uses its own incremental compiler instead of javac.

Comment: What do you mean by the compiler crashed? Do you have any stacktrace?

Comment: Even mvn clean install, gets stuck when it reaches "Compiling 172 source files to...."

Comment: Type inference is hard. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055984

Comment: Are you sure it's efficient to call `Arrays.asList(categoryRepo.findByName("Bar & Pubs").get())` repeatedly.  Shouldn't categoryMappings be a map as the name suggests?

Comment: @PeterLawrey the mappings can be different I'm mapping 100 categories from a provider to around 20 of ours ("Bar & Pubs" is one of ours), and then add then I'm adding it to our Place and I persist it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that seems to be it, thanks. Hope they somehow improve this.

Comment: @JimmyPage, can you please provide a self contained example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working on [JEP-215 Tiered attribution](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/215). The goal of this JEP is to improve the attribution code in javac, and as a side effect to improve the compiler's performance. For example the code listed in bug [JDK-8055984](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055984) is compiled by "normal" Javac9 in: a lot of time! The current version of tiered attribution compiles it in ~2.5 seconds, which is much better. Tiered attribution's code is not public yet. I hope it will be so soon. In the meantime this kind or reports are really useful.

**Edit**: if anyone want to give a try to tiered attribution, still in development, please check this announcement: [tiered attribution for all](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2015-March/009353.html)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
List<Pair<String, List<Category>>> categoryMappings = null;
```

to

```
List<? extends Pair<String, List<Category>>> categoryMappings = null;
```

See if this speeds it up.  My JDK/IDE (IntelliJ) wont compile your code snippet otherwise.

Comment: I think its a better practice, I did the change. however it did not solve the issue. Eclipse crashes and mvn clean install still takes hours to run on "Compiling" part.